# Snap SVG Iterate over Object to build Animate properties

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm looking to write a function involving Snap SVG that would allow me to pass in an object or array of values through which I can iterate to build the animation properties.

For example, if I could pass:
[transform: 't100,100', transform: 'r10,10,10']

Into this:

```
animateElementWithSnap: function(element, parentSVG, animationValues, duration, easing) {
        var s = Snap.select("#"+ parentSVG),
            theElement = s.select("#"+ element);

        theElement.animate({
           // Iterate over Object.keys(animationValues)
           transform: 't100,100',
           transform: 'r10,10,10'
        }, duration, easing);
    }
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused what the problem is, you can just pass animate() an object, so I'm not sure if you are just overcomplicating what isn't necessary. Maybe if you include the source on a jsfiddle it may be a bit more obvious what the problem is. I also don't quite understand what you are trying to do with 2 transforms, as opposed to one combined transform string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over an array of properties.  You can actually create the animationValues as an object.

Given you set up your values like this:

```
var animationValues = {
    transform: 't100,100',
    transform: 'r10,10,10'
};
```

Then you can change your animate call like this:

```
animateElementWithSnap: function(element, parentSVG, animationValues, duration, easing) {
    var s = Snap.select("#"+ parentSVG),
        theElement = s.select("#"+ element);

    theElement.animate(animationValues, duration, easing);
};
```